# What is the best solution to backing up your computer to an external HD?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

I have an external hard drive that I would like to make backups to, what I would like is have a program that is easy to set up to accomplish this for me.

Thanks